# use variable to set another variable

Tags: bash, shell

What I'm trying to do is the following. 
My script reads the name of folders in current directory:

`for D in */ ; do
 echo $D
 done`

The result is:

folder1/ 
folder2/ 
folder3/

After this I can use the $D for other purposes.
I have another variable : PATH
What I want to do is make variable PATH dependent of the $D in a form of a list or something.

Like if $D is folder1/ then PATH is /var/lib/idk

if $D is folder2/ then PATH is /home/lib/user

if $D is folder3/ then PATH is something completly different

Then i'd like to use $PATH in an svn checkout like this

`svn checkout svn://svn.something.local/home/idk/$PATH`

I've red that it's possible with array, but the examples are too compicated for someone on my level.
Can someone make a more simple example?

Thanx in advance

Comment: You're modifying `$PATH`? I ***strongly*** suggest you use another name, e.g. lowercase `$path`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, uppercase variable names are not recommended, and `PATH` is a perfect example of why not!

Since you tagged Bash, you could use an associative array:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -A paths
paths=( 
  [folder1/]=/var/lib/idk
  [folder2/]=/home/lib/user
  [folder3/]='something completely different' 
)

for dir in */; do
  path=${paths[$dir]}
  echo svn checkout svn://svn.something.local/home/idk/$path
done
```

Remove the `echo` if you're happy with the output.

Answer (score 0):

Use `case`:

```
case $D in
  folder1*)
    path=/var/lib/idk
    ;;
  folder2*)
    path=/home/lib/user
    ;;
  folder3*)
    path=some other thing
    ;;
  *)
    echo "Error, Unknown variable D"
    ;;
esac
```